# Socket.io connected property is always false

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I am trying to create a private messaging app. The socket connects at first but then when I try to emit any event from the client side, it shows that socket.connected property is false.
Please help me out.

Here's is my client side code, Please note that socket.on("users") part works correctly because all of it happens when the socket it connected. It means the connection part is happening correctly. After that whenever I try to call a function that emits a socket event, it shows that socket.connected property is false and doesnt do anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
var connectionOptions = {
    transports: ["websocket"],
    autoConnect: false,
  };
  socket = io("http://localhost:3001", connectionOptions);

  socket.on("connection _error", (err) => {
    if (err.message === "invalid username") {
      console.log("ERROR");
    }
  });

  socket.on("users", (users) => {
    users.forEach((user) => {
      user.self = user.userID === socket.id;
      //initReactiveProperties(user);
    });

    socket.on("user connected", (user) => {
      // TODO
      setUsers((existingusers) => [...existingusers, user]);
      console.log(user);
    });
    // put the current user first, and then sort by username
    users = users.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.self) return -1;
      if (b.self) return 1;
      if (a.username < b.username) return -1;
      return a.username > b.username ? 1 : 0;
    });
    //console.log(users);
  });

  socket.on("private message", ({ content, from }) => {
    console.log(content);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const username = localStorage.getItem("username");
    console.log(username);
    socket.auth = { username };
    socket.connect();
  }, []);

  function SendMessage() {
    socket.emit("test", "hello");
    // selectedChatUser
    console.log(socket.connected);
    if (selectChatUser) {
      socket.emit("private message", {
        content: "hello there",
        to: selectChatUser.userID,
      });
      console.log("Message Sent");
    }
  }
```

And here is my server side code:

```
const app = require("express")();
const httpServer = require("http").createServer(app);
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());
const options = {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
};
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, options);

io.use((socket, next) => {
  const username = socket.handshake.auth.username;
  if (!username) {
    return next(new Error("invalid usernmae"));
  }
  socket.username = username;
  next();
});

io.on("connect", (socket) => {
  console.log("New connection");
  const users = [];
  for (let [id, socket] of io.of("/").sockets) {
    users.push({
      userID: id,
      username: socket.username,
    });
  }
  socket.broadcast.emit("user connected", {
    userID: socket.id,
    username: socket.username,
  });
  socket.emit("users", users);

  socket.on("test", () => {
    console.log("test");
  });

  socket.on("private message", ({ content, to }) => {
    console.log(content);
    console.log("hello there");
    socket.to(to).emit("private message", {
      content,
      from: socket.id,
    });
  });
});

httpServer.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log("Server has started");
});

// https://socket.io/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following line will re-run every time your component renders, losing reference to the socket that was actually connected:

```
socket = io("http://localhost:3001", connectionOptions);
```

You can use a ref to persist it between renders:

```
const socketRef = useRef();
socketRef.current = socket;
// use socketRef.current everywhere else in your code
```

Comment: Yeah I understand and problem was solved. Thanks a lot !!